# App Engine PHP - cant find curl.so

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, google-cloud-sdk

Run dev_appserver.py and now get an error relating to curl.so:

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\dev\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\php\php-5.5-Win32-VC11-x86\curl.so' - The specified module could not be found.

This file does appear to be missing from the directory specified but haven't touched anything and have not had this error before.

How do I resolve?

**Additional info**

I have found there is already a php.ini file in same directory as app.yaml, just a few basic lines:

```
extension = "curl.so"
;extension=C:\dev\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll
;extension=C:\dev\xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll
```

So I changed it to comment out the first line and restore the second line:

```
;extension = "curl.so"
extension=C:\dev\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll
;extension=C:\dev\xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll
```

The error now changes to cant find ...`php_curl.dll`.

Yet the file seems to be there:

[image]

So why the error now? seems the path to dll is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Curl and not Curl Lite, then you need to reference the .dll version while using a Windows based system. Create a php.ini file in the same directory as your app.yaml file add the following line to it:

```
extension = php_curl.dll
```

If instead you want to use curl lite, you can remove the line above and instead add:

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

to the php.ini file.

Comment: Original post edited to provide extra info and next steps undertaken.

Comment: If you installed the Cloud SDK correctly, you won't need to include the full path. Set the extension line exactly how I mentioned:

extension = php_curl.dll

That will tell the emulator to look for php_curl.dll in the Google Cloud SDK's PHP folder which should be located at:

C:\Users\{YOUR_USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\php\php-5.5-Win32-VC11-x86

Comment: OK its no longer showing that error now after running app_server.py, but I go to the browser and load localhost:8080 and Chrome has: localhost refused to connect